# Set up MultiIndex DataFrame from multiple CSV files in DateTime series

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a list of time series price data in CSV format that is read as follows:

```
asxList = ['ANZ', 'NAB', 'WBC']

for asxCode in asxList:
    ohlcData = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(asxCode+'.CSV', header=0)
```

Example output:

[image]

How do I assemble all the ohlcData in particular order, firstly by DateTime index, and secondly by the asxList ['ANZ', 'NAB', 'WBC'] index, then followed by the data columns?

Comment: What do you mean by "_assemble_": sort or group?

Comment: You may use `concat` and set a multilevel index, first `Date` then your tick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of dataframes, add a `code` column to each dataframe:

```
dfs = []
for asxCode in asxList:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(asxCode+'.CSV', header=0)
    df['code'] = asxCode
    dfs.append(df)
```

Concatenate the dataframes, add the `code` column to the index:

```
pd.concat(dfs).reset_index().set_index(['index', 'code'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost same with Dyz, just using `keys` from `concat`

```
asxList = ['ANZ', 'NAB', 'WBC']
l=[]
for asxCode in asxList:
    l.append(pd.DataFrame.from_csv(asxCode+'.CSV', header=0))

pd.concat(l,keys=asxList)
```

Comment: You can do `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_csv(asxCode+'.CSV', header=0) for asxCode in asxList], keys=asxList)`.

Comment: Thanks Wen and the single-line code by DyZ is very Pythonic!